# How to add Multiple EditText objects in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to add a second blank for users to enter a second text in a second text box in the alert dialog, how do I do this? I have tried to add a text box directly but doing so only replaces the current text that users read when the alert dialog appears and also my second text box doesn't appear

This is my current code

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add_task:

            final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Add a new task")
                    .setMessage("What do you want to do next?")
                    .setView(taskEditText)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            values.put(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, task);
                            db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
                                    null,
                                    values,
                                    SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                            db.close();
                            updateUI();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `LinearLayout` and add your `Edittext's` to it

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
final EditText taskEditText1 = new EditText(this);
final EditText taskEditText2 = new EditText(this);
layout.addView(taskEditText1);
layout.addView(taskEditText2);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Add a new task")
                    .setMessage("What do you want to do next?")
                    .setView(layout) //<-- add layout
```

Comment: sry for the noob question but my match_parent and wrap_content isn't working in your code , am i missing something , also will i have to change 


this line String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());

as i now have two taskEditText to work with

Comment: @noob4321 you just have to statically import them

Comment: not working, no construct for LinearLayout with those params

Answer (score 0):

```
val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    alert.setTitle("Buy Airtime")
    alert.setMessage("Enter phone details and amount to buy airtime.")

    val layout = LinearLayout(context)
    layout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

    val mobileNoET = EditText(context)
    mobileNoET.setSingleLine()
    mobileNoET.hint = "Mobile Number"
    layout.addView(mobileNoET)

    val amountET = EditText(context)
    amountET.setSingleLine()
    amountET.hint = "Amount"
    layout.addView(amountET)

    val networkET = EditText(context)
    networkET.setSingleLine()
    networkET.hint = "Network"
    layout.addView(networkET)

    layout.setPadding(50, 40, 50, 10)

    alert.setView(layout)

    alert.setPositiveButton("Proceed") { _, _ ->
        val mobileNo = mobileNoET.text.toString()
        val amount = amountET.text.toString()
        val network = networkET.text.toString()

        Log.i("xxx",mobileNo )
        Log.i("xxx",amount )
        Log.i("xxx",network )
    }

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    alert.setCancelable(false)
    alert.show()
```